# Snytax Highlighter Not Working

Tags: syntaxhighlighter

I'm trying to display java code in html page, It's not working, it shows this error [image]
any help will be appreciated. my code look like

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shCore.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="syntaxhighlighter/styles/shCore.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shBrushJava.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="syntaxhighlighter/styles/shCoreEclipse.css" />
        
<h3>Java Code:</h3>    
<pre class="brush: java;">
public class JavaClass  {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
</pre>
 
     
   
<!-- Highlight all -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
</script>
```

when i comment the following line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="syntaxhighlighter/scripts/shCore.js"></script>
```

the above error will not appear but shows diffrent error.